# Explain this awk command

Tags: awk

Please explain what exactly this `awk` command does:

```
awk '$0!~/^$/{print $0}'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It removes blank lines.  The condition is `$0` (the whole line) does not match `!~` the regexp `/^$/` (the beginning of the line immediately followed by the end of the line).

Similar to `grep -v '^$'`

Answer (score 5):

It prints non-empty input lines. Note: "Empty" does not mean "blank", in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your example could be rewritten as simply:

```
awk '!/^$/'
```

or

```
sed '/^$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Ben Jackson and the others said, it removes completely empty lines. Not the ones with one ore more whitespaces, but the zero character long ones. We will never know if this was the intended behaviour.

I'd like to remark, that the code is at least redundant if not even triple redundant depending on what it's used for.

What it does is that it prints the input line to the output **if** the input line is **not** the empty line.

Since the standard behaviour of awk is, that the input line is printed if a condition without a following program block is met, this would suffice:

```
awk '$0!~/^$/' or even shorter awk '$0!=""'
```

If you could be sure, that no line would be parsed to zero, even a

```
awk'$0'
```

could do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Make it readable first...

```
echo '$0!~/^$/{print $0}' | a2p
==>
$, = ' ';
$\ = "\n";

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ !~ /^$/) {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

And the interpret. In this case, don't print empty lines.

Comment: -1. I like Perl, but "readable" is in the eye of the beholder.  Is `$_` better than `$0`? I think this answer is not very helpful.